# You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to a model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to develop a web app that offers to create a league of minigames on django. At the moment when creating the data base I get the following error:

> You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to juego without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).

Here's my class `Juego` on the file `models.py`:

```
class Juego(models.Model):
   nombre_juego = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   record = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10000000, decimal_places=3)
   fecha_inicio = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
   fecha_fin = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
   enlace = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

after the last migration i added the following class to the model:

```
class Juegan(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    nombre_juego = models.ManyToManyField(Juego)
    puntuacion = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10000000, decimal_places=3)
```

Comment: What else have you exactly done since tour last migration?

Comment: i add the following class to models:

Comment: Please use the edit link to provide more details in your question and refrain from adding them in comments!

Comment: I just changed the question @Wtower

Comment: Did you have `primary_key=True` on a different field before?

Comment: No @Alasdair I only have import the User class, I don't know if it's matters.

Comment: I can't see what the problem is. If you don't have important data in the database, you might find it easiest to recreate the database, remove the migrations in your app, then recreate the migrations.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the code you have right now.  I just made a django project and ran it all:

models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Juego(models.Model):
   nombre_juego = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   record = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10000000, decimal_places=3)
   fecha_inicio = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
   fecha_fin = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
   enlace = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class Juegan(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    nombre_juego = models.ManyToManyField(Juego)
    puntuacion = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10000000, decimal_places=3)
```

migration 1:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations
import django.utils.timezone


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Juego',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('nombre_juego', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('record', models.DecimalField(max_digits=10000000, decimal_places=3)),
                ('fecha_inicio', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
                ('fecha_fin', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
                ('enlace', models.CharField(max_length=1000)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

migration 2:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations
from django.conf import settings


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('jugando', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Juegan',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('puntuacion', models.DecimalField(max_digits=10000000, decimal_places=3)),
                ('nombre_juego', models.ManyToManyField(to='jugando.Juego')),
                ('user', models.ManyToManyField(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

ran this:

```
brendan@brendan-UX305FA:~/Devel/test/juego$ python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'jugando':
  0002_juegan.py:
    - Create model Juegan
brendan@brendan-UX305FA:~/Devel/test/juego$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, messages
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, jugando, auth, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying jugando.0002_juegan... OK
```

The issue has to be somewhere other than the snippets you showed: maybe a data integrity issue.  You should consider starting over with a fresh database if you don't have any important data yet.